# Error: Failed dependencies while downgrading libcurl

Tags: yum, rhel6, downgrade

I'm trying to downgrade my libcurl version from 7.54.0 to 7.52.1 in Linux Red Hat 6.

I run:

```
[root@fossa yhchai]# sudo rpm -Uvh http://nervion.us.es/city-fan/yum-repo/rhel6/x86_64/curl-7.52.1-1.0.cf.rhel6.x86_64.rpm
```

and it gives me a fail dependencies error:

```
Retrieving http://nervion.us.es/city-fan/yum-repo/rhel6/x86_64/curl-7.52.1-1.0.cf.rhel6.x86_64.rpm
error: Failed dependencies:
        libcurl(x86-64) = 7.52.1-1.0.cf.rhel6 is needed by curl-7.52.1-1.0.cf.rhel6.x86_64
```

Appreciate if you guys could provide some enlightenment and solution for this, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to downgrade both (`curl` and `libcurl`) packages. If you have more dependencies, you have to downgrade them too. Here are a couple of options how to do it:

If you have `yum` installed, then do,

```
 ~]# yum downgrade curl libcurl
```

OR

```
 ~]# yum downgrade curl-7.52.1-1.0.cf.rhel6 libcurl-7.52.1-1.0.cf.rhel6
```

OR

first download the two packages to a directory `mydir`,

```
~]# cd mydir
~]# wget http://nervion.us.es/city-fan/yum-repo/rhel6/x86_64/curl-7.52.1-1.0.cf.rhel6.x86_64.rpm
~]# wget http://nervion.us.es/city-fan/yum-repo/rhel6/x86_64/libcurl-7.52.1-1.0.cf.rhel6.x86_64.rpm
```

And then,

```
~]# rpm -Uvh *curl*.rpm
```

Comment: Hi iamauser, thank you very much for the solution. It works!